# How to make an common area for all the activities in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to make a common area across all the activities to show the same ad in all the pages like below images. I used stack widget but it does not show that area in all the activities.

[example image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qp4Qz.jpg)

[example image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uxci.jpg)

here what I have tried,

main.dart

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<List<GridImage>>.value( 
      value: DatabaseService().images, images to get image list
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Material(
          child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 22,
              child: Home()
            ),
            Flexible(
            child: Align(
              alignment:Alignment(0, 1),
              child: Text('Hello'),
            ),
            fit: FlexFit.tight,
            flex: 2,
          )
          ],
        ),
        ) 
      ),
     );
  }
}
```

output like below image

[result of the code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGwrx.jpg)

inside Home() class I have several activities to navigate. I just want to make that bottom space(which I have added Text called 'Hello') available for all the activities in the app. I would be grateful if anyone can help me with this

Comment: What have you attempted so far? Can we see your code if you have any? Or are you just asking in case you ever want to (Which is absolutely fine).

Comment: @TheGrandJ I edited the question. I added what I have tried so far. I would be grateful if you can help me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://pub.dev/packages/ads) package. It allows you display ads as in images via `firebase_admob`. As far as i know it also allows you to create variety of ads not only stripe in the bottom of the image.

Comment: Can I use it for facebook audience network? because I use facebook ads for my app

Comment: According to google documentation of AdMob it might be possible. I have never tried to implement these two services side by side, but try this article by google. https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation/facebook

Comment: Its about mediation. Now what I want. I only intend to use facebook ads

Comment: Alight, then try this package, which is only for facebook ads https://pub.dev/packages/facebook_audience_network

Comment: You misunderstood my question I know I have to use that package but my problem is about flutter layout. Can you please read the question and help me